# Redux: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

In my redux action file below I am getting the following error - Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined. The error is pointing to the line where the code is: dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status, 'LOGIN_FAIL'));

//Action File Login User

```js
export const login = ({email, password, history}) => dispatch => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    };

    const body = JSON.stringify({email, password});

    axios
        .post('/api/user/login/', body, config)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
                payload: res.data,
            });
            history.push('/userfeed');
        })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status, 'LOGIN_FAIL'));
            dispatch({
                type: LOGIN_FAIL,
            });
        });
};
```

```
//Return errors
export const returnErrors = (message, status, id = null) =>{
  return{
    type: GET_ERRORS,
    payload: {message, status, id}
  };
};
```

Comment: That would be because the `response` key does not exist on the `err` object when that line of code runs.

Comment: I would say wrap your dispatch in an `if` statement to make sure the `response` exists.

Comment: That doesnt work. I don't get whats wrong. I started getting that error when I added the history.push() code. I updated my post with the returnError.

Comment: The other thing is, console.log() isnt displaying. I added console.log(err) just before dispatch of returnErrors but nothing shows up on my console

Comment: What if you console log `res`, does that show and have data?

Comment: Just tried it and it didnt work. Its weird I dont know why the my cmd panel console isnt showing anything

Comment: Sorry I was looking at my command panel console which is why I was not seeing the error on there. I looked into my browser console and I saw the error. It said undefined

Comment: if you comment out the `.catch` do you still get the error? (just eliminating possibilities here)

Comment: Not the same error. The error I get now is: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: so `history` is nothing... I'm assuming whatever is calling `login` is not passing in history properly.

Comment: From my frontend login component? I can add that code on here as well if thats what you are talking about?

Comment: I console.logged histroy and it shows as undefined

Comment: yes, that was expected. Check the location you are calling the login function from to make sure you are passing in history correctly.